# Duplicate key error with SonarQube 5.2

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I've been trying out SonarQube 5.2, but I'm getting errors such as these:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  
Cause:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.projects' with unique index 'projects_uuid'. The duplicate key value is (AVDTnvuxTcMzGBo2P2Fw).
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.component.ComponentMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.projects' with unique index 'projects_uuid'. The duplicate key value is (AVDTnvuxTcMzGBo2P2Fw).
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.db.component.ComponentDao.insert(ComponentDao.java:282) ~[sonar-db-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistComponent(PersistComponentsStep.java:172) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistAndPopulateCache(PersistComponentsStep.java:164) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.visitModule(PersistComponentsStep.java:130) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep.execute(PersistComponentsStep.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:78) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.run(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:55) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

This only occurs if the solution I'm trying to analyse has more than one project. The same projects analyze just fine with SonarQube 5.1.2. I have the following configuration:

- SonarQube 5.2 (with a SQL Server 2012 database)
- C# 4.3
- Java 3.7
- LDAP 1.5
- Git 1.1
- SVN 1.2
- JavaScript 2.8

Anyone else ran into this problem?

Comment: Do you confirm that your DB is case sensitive ?
Can you also send us the following file : .sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties ?
Thanks

Comment: Of course, the case sensitivity was the problem. I set up a new environment to test out 5.2 before deploying it for day-to-day use, so I also set up a fresh new database and forgot that step. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, it's a good news !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is coming from the fact that db and tables must be case sensitive.

Comment: As a reminder this is a requirement listed at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements