# SonarQube - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.projects'

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I keep getting this error when analyzing .net project using msbuild runner - ### Error updating database.  Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.projects' with unique index 'projects_uuid'. The duplicate key value is (AVDyMY-5YwVQNVOkEEHa).

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps:

```
2008 (MSSQL Server 10.0) with bundled Microsoft JDBC driver. Express Edition is supported.
(tick) 2012 (MSSQL Server 11.0) with bundled Microsoft JDBC driver. Express Edition is supported.
(tick) 2014 (MSSQL Server 12.0) with bundled Microsoft JDBC driver. Express Edition is supported.

(warning) Collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS)

(info) Both Windows authentication (“Integrated Security”) and SQL Server authentication are supported. See the Microsoft SQL Server section in Installing page for instructions on configuring authentication.
```

[Duplicate key error with SonarQube 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529023/duplicate-key-error-with-sonarqube-5-2)