# SonarQube not showing analysis results from Team Build

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, azure-devops

I am using SonarQube 5.2 integrated with Team Build being executed using an on prem agent connected to Visual Studio Online. The build completes and shows a summary of SonarQube results in build summary, screen shot below. However, when I navigate to it the results are not available in SonarQube dashboard. 
[image]

[image]

**I am trying to understand why the analysis results are not uploading into SonarQube dashboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as pointed out by Bogdan Gavril, since SonarQube 5.2, the analysis results are not immediately available on the server: There is a background task running on the server that does some further analysis - the project only becomes visible when that background task is completed.

You can see the status of the backgrounds tasks by navigating to: Administrator -> Projects -> Background Tasks

[image: Access Background Tasks in SonarQube]

Comment: The issue was that the database was not case-sensitive i.e. same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529023/duplicate-key-error-with-sonarqube-5-2

Comment: That again :( FYI, there is a ticket on the SonarQube platform to fail fast if the DB is not properly configured: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6884